# Persons wear same color of hats as before

Tags: probability, probability-theory

In a room there are $5$ persons with a red hat, $4$ with a green hat and $3$ with a blue hat. Something happens and their hats get mixed randomly. On average, how many persons wear hats with the same color as before? I want to find among $4.16, 4.50, 4.66, 4.00$ the nearest real number to the real mean value.

Since there are $5$ red hats, there are $5$ possible hats for the first person that wore a red hat, $4$ for the second one, ..., one for the last person.

With the above logic, there are $5!$ possibilities for the persons with a red hat, $4!$ for the persons with a green hat and $3!$ for the persons with a blue hat.

So the desired mean value is

$$\frac{5! \cdot 4! \cdot 3!}{(5+4+3)!}=\frac{5! \cdot 4! \cdot 3!}{12!}$$

But the latter tends to $0$. So I must have done something wrong. Where is my mistake?

Comment: I don't understand. A red hat person has $5$ choices for red hats, not $5!$.  I'd say:  the probability a red hat person gets a red hat is $\frac 5{12}$ and so on for the other colors, so the answer would be $5\times \frac 5{12}+4\times \frac 4{12}+3\times \frac 3{12}=4.1\overline {6}$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A red hat person has $5$ choices for red hats, not $5!$.

To solve the problem, use Linearity of Expectation.

The probability a red hat person gets a red hat is $\frac 5{12}$, for a green person it is $\frac 4{12}$ and for a blue person it is $\frac 3{12}$. It follows that  the answer would be $$5\times \frac 5{12}+4\times \frac 4{12}+3\times \frac 3{12}=\boxed {4.1\overline {6}}$$